# Вопрос про Windows Control Library и UserControl

Tags: c#

Я создал UserControl1.cs. У меня получился автономный элемент управления,т.е. никакие данные из других классов не передаются . Создал новый проект и добавил туда этот UserControl. Все работает.

Также попробовал сделать элемент управления с передачей данных с помощью конструктора :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Summa_test
{
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1 (float pp,float gg)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        p = pp;
        g = gg;
    }
    float p, h, g;
    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        h = p + g; 
        label1.Text = h.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Но при добавлении этого компонента  в Toolbox появляется ошибка: "В F:Documents and Settings..... нет компонентов, которые можно было бы поместить в эту панель элементов"
В чем причина и как исправить? Или в этот элемент управления нельзя передавать данных?

**Я написал код с использованием свойств:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace bred4
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 fff = new UserControl1();
        UserControl1.A_set = 6;
        UserControl1.B_set = 3;
        fff.Am();
    }
}
}
```

И код в UserControl:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace bred4
{
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    static float a, b; 
    float c;
    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    public static float A_set
    {
        set { a = value; }
    }
    public static float B_set
    {
        set { b = value; }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = a + b;
       label1.Text = c.ToString();
    }
    public void Am()
  {
         c = a + b;
        label1.Text = c.ToString();
  }
}
}
```

При использовании метода button1_Click() и нажатии на кнопку результат получается правильный .А при использовании метода Am()(если кнопку не нажимать) никакого результата не получается.  Как это исправить?

Comment: В данном случае создаётся новый UserControl1 и затем, после изменения свойств, собирается когда-нибудь сборщиком мусора.

Следует не создавать новый экземпляр UserControl1, а изменить уже созданный в редакторе форм, например, добавить в Form1_Load() или userControl1_Load() следующие строки:

    userControl1.A_set = 6;
    userControl1.B_set = 3;

Comment: Возникла новая проблема при использовании нестатического метода Am().
При использовании метода button1_Click() и нажатии на кнопку результат получается правильный .А при использовании метода Am()(если кнопку не нажимать) никакого результата не получается. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что при добавлении элемента управления через конструктор форм вызывается именно конструктор без параметров. Есть разные варианты достижения желаемого:

1. Создать свойства у UserControl'а и задавать их вместо передачи значений в конструктор
2. Добавлять элемент управления из кода, не используя редактор форм

Обычно предпочитают именно вариант 1, т.к. это удобнее и согласуется со стандартными Contol'ами.

Comment: а индексаторы можно использовать?
и где можно почитать о  Windows Control Library и UserControl? на msdn мне мало что понятно, а в книгах не могу найти чтобы было написано популярно и не кратко

Comment: а как вызвать индексатор? если даже конструктор без параметров не вызывается. Я пишу: UserControl1 ffа = new UserControl1(); и появляется ошибка:  Не удалось найти имя типа или пространства имен "UserControl1" (пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку?)

Comment: В объявлении UserControl1 (обычно в файлах UsercOntrol1.cs, UserControl.designer.cs) стоит посмотреть пространство имён, в котором он объявлен. Если контрол находится в другой сборке, то нужно добавить ссылку на неё.

Comment: спасибо, это помогло частично. Я дополнил свой вопрос, значения у меня все равно не передались.